# how to install vlc player from tar file

Tags: vlc

After getting vlc-2.0.3tar.gz I extracted it and then tried the `./install`, but it gave me an error. Then i did `./configure` and got this..

```
configure: error: No package 'dbus-1' found.
```

Then tried this:

```
apt-get install dbus-1
```

But I got this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What do I do next?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for building it from source? VLC 2.0.3 appears to be the current version in the Ubuntu repositories (install in software center/`sudo apt-get install vlc` in the terminal).

If you want to build it, you need -dev versions of packages to provide the headers - probably libdbus-1-dev in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The two problems are separate.

The second problem means that there is an instance of another package related software running -- for example an update. Try `ps -eaf | grep apt` or `ps -eaf | grep dpkg`. If you really get stuck, try restarting the computer (yeah, this is not the canonical way of solving things, but might be the easiest one).

As for the first problem, why are you trying to compile and install it from the tar.gz archive? Look [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/latest-stable-vlc-heading-to-ubuntu-12-04-help-test-it-now), it is possible to install it using a Ubuntu package.

Comment: Try running "apt-get install dbus-1" without using sudo and you'll get the same error. I think that's what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

To install dbus development libraries, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev
```

That said, I also think that you should simply install the Ubuntu-provided VLC (2.0.1 for Ubuntu 12.04):

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

However if you prefer to install from the tar.gz, please see this related answer:

[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: well i downloaded the vlc version from soptpedia and now want to install it as i dont want to again use internet based downloading by the software center.. so i am trying through the terminal command prompt way

Comment: I fail to understand how downloading using apt-get or sofware center is different/worse than getting it from softpedia. Still, I updated my answer with some data on how to unpack the source and compile it.

Comment: Please, refrain from shouting with all-caps.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

`sudo apt-get build-dep vlc`